# Adding monsters to party. How to balance challenge rating.

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

So a party of 4 level 4 PC's got an earth elemental. Personally I use [Kobold Fight Club](http://kobold.club/fight/#/encounter-builder)  to manage my PC's encounters. Although I don't this elemental to make the game no longer balanced when fighting battles that should be considered dangerous or difficult making them easy. In order to create this balance would the earth elemental be considered equal to 4 more PC's or equivalent level or one level 5 PC